# How to write a Windows command line application with 'updating' interface?

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface, command-line, command-line-interface

How do I go about creating a command line interface that is updatable, rather than 'line-by-line'? Ideally in C# or c++.

So for instance, the popular GPU-based bitcoin mining software cgminer, when running has a 'static' part that outputs the performance of your GPU, time running etc, and a 'moving' part that gives updates on accepted shares, errors, etc.

Comment: [Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073.aspx).

Comment: And many many PInvokes if you use C# :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than Console functions that Jerry said, there is also an ncurses-like library you could try: http://sourceforge.net/projects/curses-sharp/ I haven't tried it myself, but if done in Unix, ncurses would be the way.